# Convertir final in List<dynamic> flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Tengo el siguiente JSON:

```
"cast": [
    {
      "cast_id": 0,
      "character": "John Wick",
      "credit_id": "591d49ad925141499001b005",
      "gender": 2,
      "id": 6384,
      "name": "Keanu Reeves",
      "order": 0,
      "profile_path": "/bOlYWhVuOiU6azC4Bw6zlXZ5QTC.jpg"
    },
    {
      "cast_id": 9,
      "character": "Sofia",
      "credit_id": "5b031331925141097301b798",
      "gender": 1,
      "id": 4587,
      "name": "Halle Berry",
      "order": 1,
      "profile_path": "/hdUqx0on0cqbFuJCZtEGU42UWe5.jpg"
    },
]
```

Tengo los siguientes metodos que me agarran ese JSON y lo pasan a un modelo:

```
final respuesta=await http.get(url);
final decodedData=json.decode(respuesta.body);
final cast=new Cast.fromJSONMap(decodedData['cast']);
```

La ultima linea hace referencia a este metodo en el modelo, de ahi se mapean los datos y se guardan:

```
Cast.fromJSONMap(List<dynamic> jsonList) {
    if (jsonList == null) return;

    for (var item in jsonList) {
      final actor = new Actor.fromJSONMap(item);
      actores.add(actor);
    }
  }
```

Hasta aqui me funciona todo bien.

Resulta que tengo este otro JSON:

```
{
  "birthday": "1964-09-02",
  "known_for_department": "Acting",
  "deathday": null,
  "id": 6384,
  "name": "Keanu Reeves",
  "also_known_as": [
    "Киану Ривз",
    "كيانو ريفز",
    "키아누 리브스",
    "キアヌ・リーブス",
    "เคอานู รีฟส์",
    "基努·里维斯",
    "קיאנו ריבס",
    "Keanu Charles Reeves"
  ],
  "gender": 2,
  "biography": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "popularity": 34.892,
  "place_of_birth": "Beirut, Lebanon",
  "profile_path": "/bOlYWhVuOiU6azC4Bw6zlXZ5QTC.jpg",
  "adult": false,
  "imdb_id": "nm0000206",
  "homepage": null
}
```

Resulta que quiero recuperarlo y mapearlo como el anterior, pero este JSON no tiene un `xxx:[]` que lo esta envolviendo como el ejemplo anterior, por tanto, a la hora de pasarlo para mapearlo usando la mismos metodos:

```
    final respuesta=await http.get(url);
    final decodedData=json.decode(respuesta.body);
    final person=new DetalleActor.fromJSONMap(decodedData);
```

La ultima linea como la anterior pasa al siguiente metodo para mapearla:

```
DetalleActor.fromJSONMap(List<dynamic> jsonList) {
    if (jsonList == null) return;

    for (var item in jsonList) {
      final persona = new Persona.fromJSONMap(item);
      personas.add(persona);
    }
  }
```

Me lanza el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
_TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' 
is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>')
```

Segun yo, es por que esta esperando algo como `decodedData[xxx]` pero no se como resolverlo.

**EDIT**

**CLASE/MODELO PERSONA**

```
class DetalleActor{

  List<Persona> personas=new List();

  DetalleActor();

  DetalleActor.fromJSONMap(List<dynamic> jsonList) {
    if (jsonList == null) return;

    for (var item in jsonList) {
      final persona = new Persona.fromJSONMap(item);
      personas.add(persona);
    }
  }
}
class Persona {
  String birthday;
  String knownForDepartment;
  String deathday;
  int id;
  String name;
  List<String> alsoKnownAs;
  int gender;
  String biography;
  double popularity;
  String placeOfBirth;
  String profilePath;
  String adult;
  String imdbId;
  String homepage;

  Persona({
    this.birthday,
    this.knownForDepartment,
    this.deathday,
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.alsoKnownAs,
    this.gender,
    this.biography,
    this.popularity,
    this.placeOfBirth,
    this.profilePath,
    this.adult,
    this.imdbId,
    this.homepage,
  });

  Persona.fromJSONMap(Map<String, dynamic> json){
      birthday=json['birthday'];
      knownForDepartment=json['known_for_department'];
      deathday=json['death_day'];
      id=json['id'];
      name=json['name'];
      alsoKnownAs=json['also_known_as'].cast<String>();
      gender=json['gender'];
      biography=json['biography'];
      popularity=json['popularity'] / 1;
      placeOfBirth=json['place_of_birth'];
      profilePath=json['profile_path'];
      adult=json['adult'];
      imdbId=json['imdb_id'];
      homepage=json['homepage'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos la clase `Persona` ?

Comment: @diegoveloper agrego el resto de la clase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segun lo que entiendo es que `Persona` son los elementos que están dentro de `also_know_as`, entonces el error que tienes es porque `DetalleActor.fromJSONMap(List<dynamic> jsonList)`  está esperando una `List` cuando debería esperar un `Map` o `dynamic`.

Ya no es necesario la clase `DetalleActor`, con esto lo solucionarias:

```
class Persona {
  String birthday;
  String knownForDepartment;
  String deathday;
  int id;
  String name;
  List<String> alsoKnownAs;
  int gender;
  String biography;
  double popularity;
  String placeOfBirth;
  String profilePath;
  String adult;
  String imdbId;
  String homepage;

  Persona({
    this.birthday,
    this.knownForDepartment,
    this.deathday,
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.alsoKnownAs,
    this.gender,
    this.biography,
    this.popularity,
    this.placeOfBirth,
    this.profilePath,
    this.adult,
    this.imdbId,
    this.homepage,
  });

  Persona.fromJSONMap(Map<String, dynamic> json){
      birthday=json['birthday'];
      knownForDepartment=json['known_for_department'];
      deathday=json['death_day'];
      id=json['id'];
      name=json['name'];
      alsoKnownAs=json['also_known_as'].map((val) => val).toList();
      gender=json['gender'];
      biography=json['biography'];
      popularity=json['popularity'] / 1;
      placeOfBirth=json['place_of_birth'];
      profilePath=json['profile_path'];
      adult=json['adult'];
      imdbId=json['imdb_id'];
      homepage=json['homepage'];
  }
}
```

Lo usarías así

```
    final respuesta=await http.get(url);
    final decodedData=json.decode(respuesta.body);
    final person= Persona.fromJSONMap(decodedData);
```

Comment: Según leyendo el codigo solo estas tomando en cuenta el `also_know_as` y que pasa con el resto de valores a la hora de iterear en el jsonList (que para entonces solo va a tener lo que tenga eso)?

Comment: Tendrias que mostrar las entidades detalle actor y persona para ver donde quieres guardar la otra info

Comment: ya veo, el json que muestras te retorna solo un objeto Persona, entonces no necesitas una lista , porque usas List ?

Comment: reutilizo codigo, como me sirvio lo uso con otros y omito esos detalles al reutilizar, en este caso no necesito una lista de personas/actores puesto que solo es uno, como puedo resolver eso?